# Sumar varios BigDecimal Java/AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, array, bigdecimal

estoy iniciando en android y me surgió un problema que me tiene un poco atrapado.

Resulta que tengo varios datos BigDecimal que ya se encuentran definidos los cuales necesito sumar y que me entreguen un total, estaba pensando en hacer un arreglo con todas las variables (que pueden ser null) e ir agregando a un contador pero la suma de los datos pero necesito un poco de ayuda por favor

Comment: Necesitas ayuda en qué parte exactamente?

Comment: para sumar todas las variables BigDecimal, son 28 variables y cada una tiene un entero y 3 decimales, pero segun el flujo de la aplicacion pueden existir algunos con valor null entonces tengo que tomar solo los que estan != 0 y sumarlos para que me devuelva un Double o un Float... no se si me explico bien la verdad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes que sumar varios `BigDecimal` y es posible que hayan valores nulos, entonces usa un `Stream`, filtra y reduce:

```
public BigDecimal sum(BigDecimal... values){
   return Arrays
                .stream(values)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
}
```

Ahora, si los `BigDecimals` ya los tienes en una `List`, o una `Collection`, es más sencillo aún porque dierctamente invocas `listOcollection.stream().filter...`

Comment: Muchas Gracias, Me funciono al 100%  :D eres un genio

Answer (score 0):

No me quedo claro tu consulta, pero fijate si te sirve este snippet rápido y simples (no lo probe) si es lo que necesitas. Corrige lo que necesites para ajustar a tu implementación

```
    public BigDecimal sumar(BigDecimal[] array) {
        BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(0);
        for (BigDecimal num : array) {
            if(num!=null)
                result.add(num);
            
        }
        return result;
    }
```